# Very specific query - it can be solved?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**stamps**

- primary stamp_id,
- firstStampIdInSerie_id (is same for stamps from one serie)
- derivatedStamp_id (mark stamp_id (from the table) which belong to stamp_id of the same row)

**stampsincatalogs**

- catalogueNember_prepend, catalogue_number and catalogueNumber_append (these columns determine catalogue number)

This query which is quite simplified, but still work. Return range of series and number stamps, but from range of derivate serie return only first catalogueNumber and numberDerivatedStamps is not correct (show same number lime numberStamps). I think that is proble with GROUP BY. Is possible to put together query which will do what should do?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', CONCAT_WS('/', s.catalogueNumber_prepend,
       MIN(s.catalogue_number), s.catalogueNumber_append), 
       IF (MAX(s.catalogue_number) != MIN(s.catalogue_number), 
       CONCAT_WS('/', s.catalogueNumber_prepend, MAX(s.catalogue_number),
       s.catalogueNumber_append), NULL)) AS `rangeOfCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(s.catalogue_number) AS `numberStamps`, CONCAT_WS('-', 
       CONCAT_WS('/', ds.catalogueNumber_prepend, MIN(ds.catalogue_number),
       ds.catalogueNumber_append), 
       IF (MAX(ds.catalogue_number) != MIN(ds.catalogue_number), 
       CONCAT_WS('/', ds.catalogueNumber_prepend, 
       MAX(ds.catalogue_number), ds.catalogueNumber_append), NULL)) AS `rangeOfDerivatedCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(ds.catalogue_number) AS `numberDerivatedStamps` FROM `stamps`
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `s` ON stamps.stamp_id = s.stamp_id
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `ds` ON stamps.derivatedStamp_id = ds.stamp_id
GROUP BY `firstStampIdInSerie_id`
```

**TABLE stamps**

```
stamp_id | firstStampsIdInSerie_id | derivatedStamp_id
1        | 1                       | 6
2        | 1                       | NULL
3        | 3                       | NULL
4        | 3                       | NULL
5        | 3                       | NULL
6        | 6                       | 1
```

**TABLE stampsincatalogs**

```
id | stamp_id | catalogueNumber_prepend | catalogue_number | catalogueNumber_append
1  | 1        | NULL                    | 100              | A
2  | 2        | NULL                    | 101              | A
3  | 3        | NULL                    | 102              | A
4  | 4        | NULL                    | 103              | C
5  | 5        | NULL                    | 104              | C
6  | 6        | B                       | 8                | NULL
```

**Expected result:**

```
100/A - 102/A | 3 | B/8           | 1
103/C - 104/C | 2 | NULL          | 0
6/B           | 1 | 100/A - 102/A | 3
```

**Given result:**

```
100/A - 102/A | 3 | B/8   | 1
103/C - 104/C | 2 | NULL  | 0
6/B           | 1 | 100/A | 1
```

Thank everyones for advices

Tomas

Edit: I'am sorry I inserted my first question, so now it is formatted:).

---

I solved, but it is unuseable, because query durate 53 seconds:(. How can I optimize?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', 
                 CONCAT_WS('/',
                           s.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                           MIN(s.catalogue_number),
                           s.catalogueNumber_append), 
                 IF (MAX(s.catalogue_number) != MIN(s.catalogue_number), 
                     CONCAT_WS('/',
                               s.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                               MAX(s.catalogue_number),
                               s.catalogueNumber_append), 
                     NULL))                AS `rangeOfCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(s.catalogue_number)  AS `numberStamps`, 
       CONCAT_WS('-', 
                 CONCAT_WS('/',
                           ds.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                           MIN(ds.catalogue_number),
                           ds.catalogueNumber_append), 
                 IF (MAX(ds.catalogue_number) != MIN(ds.catalogue_number), 
                     CONCAT_WS('/',
                               ds.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                               MAX(ds.catalogue_number),
                               ds.catalogueNumber_append), 
                     NULL))                AS `rangeOfDerivatedCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ds.catalogue_number) AS `numberDerivatedStamps` 
FROM `stamps`
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `s` ON stamps.stamp_id = s.stamp_id
LEFT JOIN `stamps` AS `tmp` ON tmp.firstStampIdInSerie_id = stamps.derivatedStamp_id
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `ds` ON tmp.stamp_id = ds.stamp_id
GROUP BY `firstStampIdInSerie_id`
```

Comment: could you format your query please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by decrease of duration query on 0,03 sec

```
LEFT JOIN `stamps` AS `tmp` ON tmp.firstStampIdInSerie_id = stamps.derivatedStamp_id AND tmp.country_id = stamps.country_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you just need to change your `COUNT(...)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` - like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', 
                 CONCAT_WS('/',
                           s.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                           MIN(s.catalogue_number),
                           s.catalogueNumber_append), 
                 IF (MAX(s.catalogue_number) != MIN(s.catalogue_number), 
                     CONCAT_WS('/',
                               s.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                               MAX(s.catalogue_number),
                               s.catalogueNumber_append), 
                     NULL))                AS `rangeOfCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.catalogue_number)  AS `numberStamps`, 
       CONCAT_WS('-', 
                 CONCAT_WS('/',
                           ds.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                           MIN(ds.catalogue_number),
                           ds.catalogueNumber_append), 
                 IF (MAX(ds.catalogue_number) != MIN(ds.catalogue_number), 
                     CONCAT_WS('/',
                               ds.catalogueNumber_prepend,
                               MAX(ds.catalogue_number),
                               ds.catalogueNumber_append), 
                     NULL))                AS `rangeOfDerivatedCatNumbers`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ds.catalogue_number) AS `numberDerivatedStamps` 
FROM `stamps`
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `s` ON stamps.stamp_id = s.stamp_id
LEFT JOIN `stampsincatalogs` AS `ds` ON stamps.derivatedStamp_id = ds.stamp_id
GROUP BY `firstStampIdInSerie_id`
```

COUNT(x) returns the total number of non-null values of x found within the group, while COUNT(DISTINCT x) returns how many different values of x were found.

Comment: It doesn't solve that. DISTINCT in first case doesn't influence result, because catalogueNumbers are unique. From some reason second DISTINCT return 0 or 1 (last time returned the same value like first COUNT), because range of derivated stamps is always null or first stamp from that range. I need to enable to second concat choose from all derivated stamps of serie to obtain range (not only first stamp).

Comment: @user1047282, can you include some sample data in your question?

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I insert sample data here?

Comment: Query your database for a representative set of data from each table (just a few rows). Edit your question, then copy and paste your results into the end of the question. Save the amended question.

Comment: I didn't know how to formatted it, but I solved that. It aren't really data, in tables are more columns and different data, but for example it's good:).

Comment: @user1047282: Tomas, from your test data I would expect the series beginning with stamp 1 to have 2 stamps and 1 derivated stamp, the series beginning with stamp 3 to have 3 stamps and 0 derivated stamps, and the series beginning with stamp 6 to have 1 stamp and 1 derivated stamp. This is also what the query returns. Please can you show what results you would expect from this data, and why?

Comment: Mark is there small difference. Query doesn't return range of derivated stamps and correct number derivated stamps (first two columns are ok). Now I solve it by query to each serie which has some derivated stamp. That means many queries. This query could solve it by one query together and is really close to correct result. Is possible to return what I would like?

Comment: I expect them, because I need to list them.

Comment: Mark, do you think that is possible or no to solve it by one query?